# App Invites for friends in Facebook using iOS 8.2 "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I followed facebook documents to develop invite friend to ios app from here: [App Invites for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios) ... Here is my code:

```
    @implementation ViewController  
    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content;
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] initWithAppLinkURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/1569122770021958"]];
        //optionally set previewImageURL
        content.previewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg"];
     }
```

And then I have defined an action button as follow:

```
- (IBAction)InviteFriends:(id)sender {
    // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content delegate:sender];    
}
```

However I received an error as follow:

```
2015-04-30 19:09:06.850 LoopApp[6338:120645] -[UIButton appInviteDialog:didCompleteWithResults:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbdd870f9d0
2015-04-30 19:09:06.852 LoopApp[6338:120645] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton appInviteDialog:didCompleteWithResults:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbdd870f9d0'
```

It says I haven't defined `appInviteDialog:didCompleteWithResults:` so I added this method as follow:

```
- (void) appInviteDialog: (FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialoge didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"Session connection failed with error %@",[error self]);
}
```

I can go all the steps to select my friends and when I press button to share it shares but when it wants to go back to app crashes and it give me same error as above. I appreciate if anyone can help me why this is happening.

```
 -[UIButton appInviteDialog:didCompleteWithResults:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fabc3dbb840
2015-04-30 19:23:29.305 LoopApp[6423:125823] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton appInviteDialog:didCompleteWithResults:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fabc3dbb840'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed0ea75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e5febb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ed15d1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec6d9dc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec6d578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   LoopApp                             0x000000010dfb71e1 -[FBSDKAppInviteDialog _invokeDelegateDidCompleteWithResults:] + 297
    6   LoopApp                             0x000000010dfb70a5 -[FBSDKAppInviteDialog _handleCompletionWithDialogResults:error:] + 67
    7   LoopApp                             0x000000010dfb6ed9 __28-[FBSDKAppInviteDialog show]_block_invoke + 131
    8   LoopApp                             0x000000010df92f51 -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] + 194
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecde7fc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ebde204 _CFXNotificationPost + 2484
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010e158df8 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010f33bfc8 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 363
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010f350ea2 -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:] + 2648
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112831243 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec43c7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec399c5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec39785 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ec38bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113230a58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010f341580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    21  LoopApp                             0x000000010df88f93 main + 115
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001114ff145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are implementing the protocol FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate in your class? What I mean is something like this:

On your .h:
    @interface AMGAppDelegate : UIResponder <FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate>


On your .m:
    - (void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)dialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
    {
        NSLog(@"Invite dialog done!");
    }

    - (void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)dialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"Invite dialog failed %@!", [error description]);
    }

Comment: @corvuszero that helped!

Comment: @corvuszero, thanks. This worked

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting your button as the delegate for the FBSDKAppInviteDialog.  The UIButton does not conform to the FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate protocol and therefore it crashes.

To fix this, change your code so that the delegate is *nil* or *self* (if self conforms to the FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate protocol):

```
- (IBAction)InviteFriends:(id)sender {

    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
}
```